# How to reduce features/dimensions before running K-means?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, feature-selection

I have a data set of 3000 rows and 50 columns (features). I plan to use K-means to cluster the samples. I know out of the 50 features, some of them are correlated, others are useless.  I understand I can use PCA to reduce its dimension but I would also know how to find out the most important features.

Is there an algorithm that'll tell me which features are most important?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate on [stats.se].

Comment: Define "most important"?

Comment: =most important= the features that are most significant in helping identify the most helpful clusters.